# Voiceflow issue for Google Action/Voice - crashing after " 'suggestions' will be ignored since they are used in 'final_response' "

Tags: voice

I'm using VoiceFlow to create a simple music streaming app that plays MP3s and allows the user to stop/start/skip/replay track as per the default methods.

It works fine with Alexa but when I test it in Google Action/Voice, I get the following error right after it started playing the first file (which starts automatically per my program):

```
UnnecessaryField final_response.rich_response: 'suggestions' will be ignored since they are used in 'final_response'.
```

And the following is the debug info from Google Action:

```
{
  "response": "Alright. Getting the test version of my test app.\nHello, welcome to My music. I'll now play my favorite My music for you. You can skip ahead to the next track by saying, Hey Google, next. Or go back to the previous one by saying, Hey Google, previous. You can also pause the music by saying, Hey Google, pause. If you want to stop the music, say Hey Google, stop.Sorry, something went wrong. When you're ready, give it another try.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "Evwo5dm...",
  "audioResponse": "//NExG...",
  "ssmlMarkList": [],
  "debugInfo": {
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=b1eb03ce32b1' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImVlNGRiZDA2YzA2NjgzkZGNhNmI4OGMzZTQ3M2I2OTE1YjkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJiYXJvcXVlbXVzaWMtNDQ3OWQiLCJuYmYiOjE1NzA2NTE2OTQsImlhdCI6MTU3MDY1MTk5NCwiZXhwIjoxNTcwNjUyMTE0LCJqdGkiOiI4DK0Q4nY_KgaP57R_U0BLbsXzsraHwEiwzrJOTtu-VBlypZ0ujPph6WWGzlmfRhek09QjaCTVAR9gQOzrfkvnMwrmLH9CskopziyVRK3Yj99IArZp5bht0uvma78p-mxYwVfmGpDLt2A2nVpx3P-XMaswq-b3WA-s3-Y3sNpZO5MPkSmATXWxFdoA9xnKpWrGSbJ3TksylVygrhFPzw_gQ2bQ'  -A Google-ActionsOnGoogle/1.0 -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2019-10-09T20:13:04Z\",\"userStorage\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"userId\\\":\\\"2cd086-9896-4ddf-a59c-a2d9a3229\\\"}}\",\"userVerificationStatus\":\"VERIFIED\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABwppHFmu4qLfj_d0VPLm1k4MJOFKTmjb8NQJ6iH5TOJBilnPK5Gf1z-hvlIMqB8XVpP\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"Talk to my test app\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}'",
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2019-10-09T20:13:04Z\",\"userStorage\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"userId\\\":\\\"2c60d086-6-4ddf-a59c-a21c3229\\\"}}\",\"userVerificationStatus\":\"VERIFIED\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABwppHxEQQ7pSIgVULfj_d0VPLm1kTmjb8NQJ6iHHDWaxHI5TOJBilnlIMqB8XVpP\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"Talk to my test app\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}",
      "delegatedRequest": {
        "delegatedRequest": ""
      }
    },
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\n  \"conversationToken\": \"[]\",\n  \"finalResponse\": {\n    \"richResponse\": {\n      \"items\": [{\n        \"simpleResponse\": {\n          \"textToSpeech\": \"\\u003cspeak\\u003eHello, welcome to My music.  I\\u0027ll now play my favorite My music for you. You can skip ahead to the next track by  saying, Hey Google, next. Or go back to the previous one by saying, Hey Google, previous. You can also pause the music by saying, Hey Google, pause. If you want to stop the music, say Hey Google, stop.\\u003c/speak\\u003e\"\n        }\n      }, {\n        \"mediaResponse\": {\n          \"mediaType\": \"AUDIO\",\n          \"mediaObjects\": [{\n            \"name\": \"Albinoni - Adagio in G minor\",\n            \"contentUrl\": \"https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.getstoryflow.audio.production/file.mp3\"\n          }]\n        }\n      }],\n      \"suggestions\": [{\n        \"title\": \"exit\"\n      }]\n    }\n  },\n  \"responseMetadata\": {\n    \"status\": {\n      \"message\": \"Success (200)\"\n    },\n    \"queryMatchInfo\": {\n      \"queryMatched\": true,\n      \"intent\": \"4eaa-eae8-438a-880a-cc9e27a936fc\"\n    }\n  }\n}",
      "delegatedResponse": {
        "delegatedResponse": ""
      }
    },
    "sharedDebugInfoList": [
      {
        "name": "ResponseValidation",
        "debugInfo": "",
        "subDebugEntryList": [
          {
            "name": "UnnecessaryField",
            "debugInfo": "final_response.rich_response: 'suggestions' will be ignored since they are used in 'final_response'.",
            "subDebugEntryList": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "conversationBuilderExecutionEventsList": []
  },
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "simulatorMediaResponse": {
          "mediaResponse": {
            "mediaType": 1,
            "mediaObjectsList": [
              {
                "name": "File",
                "description": "",
                "contentUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.getstoryflow.audio.production/file.mp3"
              }
            ],
            "startOffsetMs": 0
          },
          "mediaSessionId": "324532373494015"
        }
      },
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Alright. Getting the test version of my test app."
        }
      },
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Hello, welcome to My music.  I'll now play my favorite My music for you. You can skip ahead to the next track by  saying, Hey Google, next. Or go back to the previous one by saying, Hey Google, previous. You can also pause the music by saying, Hey Google, pause. If you want to stop the music, say Hey Google, stop."
        }
      },
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Sorry, something went wrong. When you're ready, give it another try."
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/voice/opa/partner_icons/generic_3p_avatar.png",
    "agentStyle": {
      "primaryColor": "",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "borderRadius": 0,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "backgroundImageUrl": ""
    }
  },
  "clientError": 0,
  "is3pResponse": true,
  "clientOperationList": [
    {
      "operationType": 4,
      "startIndicatorPayLoad": {
        "status": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "operationType": 7,
      "exitIndicatorPayLoad": {
        "status": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "projectName": "",
  "renderedHtml": ""
}
```

I should be able to in interact with the app by pausing, stopping, skipping or go back to previous track.

Instead the error happens that crashes out of the app.

Obviously I have no direct access to the code as VoiceFlow is managing that as a black box.

But does any one know how I can fix it?

Comment: Is this the only thing that prints? I'm not familiar with VoiceFlow, but this message looks like a warning that doesn't directly relate to why your program is crashing.

Comment: Be a bit more descriptive in your title. You will get better responses that way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Vincent - thanks - I updated the title but I'm not sure what more information I can provide. Voiceflow is pretty much like a black box and other than the error statement I got from testing with Google Actions, I only have the debug info (which I can post separately)

Comment: @TheHansinator I've added more the debug info if that helps...